# Update a table with new values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update a table of data in excel with a unique index column with new values from a second table also with the same unique index column using a macro. I'm kinda new to VB programming, so I tried to look up a solution and I think I found something that should work, but doesn't. I sure it is something I messed up.

```
   Sub LookupAndPaste()
Dim RLookup As Long, endrowRLookup As Long
Dim r As Long, endRow As Long

endrowRLookup = Sheets("Exp data").Cells(3, 44).Value
endRow = Range("count_exp_data").Value

For RLookup = Sheets("Exp data").Cells(2, Columns("AT").Column) To Sheets("Exp data").Cells(endrowRLookup, Columns("AT").Column)
'Copy the current row
Range(Cells(RLookup, Columns("AT").Column), Cells(RLookup, Columns("CJ").Column)).Select
     Selection.Copy
    For r = 1 To endRow
        If Sheets("Exp data").Cells(r, Columns("A").Column).Value = RLookup Then 'Found
            Sheets("Exp data").Cells(r, Columns("A").Column).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

        End If
    Next r
Next RLookup
End Sub
```

Target search table is in column A to AO. List of rows with data to update is in AT to CJ and is any where from 1 to 100 rows in size.

When code is executed I end up in AT100:CJ100 in copy mode and nothing has changed.

Thanks

Comment: Haven't taken a close look, but this looks like the kind of problem that could be greatly helped by a rubber duck. http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/

Comment: As I mentioned before I am very new to VBA programming, but I did rethink if I was using the For properly on the RLookup and realized my error. I'm posting what worked in case anyone would make a similar mistake.

Comment: Glad the old rubber duck worked for you! If you're able as a new user, feel free to answer you own question and mark as accepted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sollution to my problem was my bad use of the first For

```
Sub LookupAndPaste()
Dim RLookup As Long, endrowRLookup As Long
Dim r As Long, endRow As Long

endrowRLookup = Sheets("Exp data").Cells(3, 44).Value
endRow = Range("count_exp_data").Value

For RLookup = 1 To endrowRLookup
'Copy the current row
Range(Cells(RLookup + 1, Columns("AT").Column), Cells(RLookup + 1, Columns("CJ").Column)).Select
     Selection.Copy
    For r = 1 To endRow
        If Sheets("Exp data").Cells(r, Columns("A").Column).Value = Cells(RLookup + 1, Columns("AT").Column).Value Then 'Found
            Sheets("Exp data").Cells(r, Columns("A").Column).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

        End If
    Next r
Next RLookup
End Sub
```